# Returning a concrete subtype from a generic function

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to implement a factory pattern in scala and am running into an issue of not being able to return a subtype of a trait from the apply method of the factory object, as seen here:

```
trait PlatformOrderUpdater

class WebOrderStatusUpdater() extends PlatformOrderUpdater

object PlatformUpdaterFactory {    
  def apply[T <: PlatformOrderUpdater](platformId: String): T = {

    new WebOrderStatusUpdater()
  }
}
```

The error I get here is `Expression of type WebOrderStatusUpdater doesn't conform to expected type T`. Is there a different way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure about a full solution yet but there is no reason to expect `T` to be of type `WebOrderStatusUpdater`. Depending on the type param of the call of `apply` it can be any subtype of `PlatformOrderUpdater` and can't be restricted to `WebOrderStatusUpdater`

Comment: You're getting the error because you're saying that caller of the function can parameterize it with any subtype of `PlatformOrderUpdater` and you will return that type, and then you return a `WebOrderStatusUpdater`. It's like saying "parameterize with any fruit and I will return that fruit" and then you return a banana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory.  You are trying to return a WebOrderStatusUpdater but you declared that you are returning a T.

What happens when I call

```
class SomeOtherSubtype() extends PlatformOrderUpdater
PlatformUpdaterFactory.apply[SomeOtherSubtype]("example")
```

The return type should be `SomeOtherSubtype` according to the type signature but you're method always returns a WebOrderStatusUpdater.

The solution is to remove the type parameter as it does nothing for you in that example.

```
def apply(platformId: String): PlatformOrderUpdater = {
   new WebOrderStatusUpdater()
}
```

Comment: Your solution does work but I'm not understanding why my implementation does not. `PlatformUpdaterFactory.apply` should return any subtype of `PlatformOrderUpdater`, which is what `WebOrderStatusUpdater` is. In my actual code there are multiple platform specific order status updaters, I omitted that for brevity though.

Comment: @novon It can't just be any subtype of `PlatformOrderUpdater`, it has to be the type `T`.  It is possible for `T` to be different from `WebOrderStatusUpdater`.  There's not any point to using generics in your case though, your inputs and outputs always have the same type.